# How to create a Controller Method that can return different error return codes in ASP.NET core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to return different httpstatus codes based on my return object (result). If it Isfailure, Error property holds serialized info consisting of error code and message provided from my service.
I have the Controller method below:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<BasicItemDTO> CreateValue(BasicIItemCreationDTO value)
    {
        Result<BasicItemDTO> res = ValuesService.CreateValue(value);
        if (res.IsFailure) return ErrorFromResult(res.Error);
        ActionResult<BasicItemDTO> response = CreatedAtRoute("GetValue", res.Value);
        return  response;
    }
```

and ErrorFromResult is defined as

```
protected IActionResult ErrorFromResult(string ErrorMessage)
    {
        ErrorCode = GetCode(ErrorMessage)
    ErrorDetail = GetMessage(Message);
    switch (ErrorCode)
            {
                case "BadReqest":
                    return BadRequest(ErrorDetail);
                case "Conflict":
                    ProblemDetails PD= GenerateResponse(ErrorDetail);
                    return Conflict(PD);
                case "NotFound":
                    return NotFound(ErrorDetail);
            }
}
```

I am struggling with what the return type on ErrorFromResult. What should the return type of ErrorFromResult be?

Comment: Is returning `IActionResult` giving you any error?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an API change the return type of `CreateValue` to `IActionResult` and wrap the response with a status code or `Json` like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateValue(BasicIItemCreationDTO value)
{
  Result<BasicItemDTO> res = ValuesService.CreateValue(value);
  if (res.IsFailure) return ErrorFromResult(res.Error);
  //ActionResult<BasicItemDTO> response = CreatedAtRoute("GetValue", res.Value);
  var url = Url.RouteUrl("route_name", route_values)
  return Created(url, the created value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a defualt label in the switch statement. The default label will be executed if the above cases not executed.

```
switch (ErrorCode)
{
    case "Conflict":
        ProblemDetails PD = GenerateResponse(ErrorDetail);
        return Conflict(PD);
    case "NotFound":
        return NotFound(ErrorDetail);
    default:
        return BadRequest(ErrorDetail);
}
```

In addition, as @HMZ said, you may change the return type of `CreateValue` to `IActionResult`, make it same as the return type of `ErrorFromResult`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. If I use IActionResult for CreateValue method, errorFromResult part works fine but the happy path does not compile as return type of CreatedAtRoute is not converted to IActionResult. You need to use 3 parameter implementation of CreateAtRoute. Below code compiles and runs as expected.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateValue(BasicIItemCreationDTO value)
    {
        Result<BasicItemDTO> res = ValuesService.CreateValue(value);
        if (res.IsFailure) return ErrorFromResult(res.Error);
        IActionResult response = CreatedAtRoute("GetValue",new {ValueId= res.Value.Id },res.Value);
        return  response;
    }
```

Thanks for the tip on default for switch. I left it out for brevity since it was not directly related to the question.